# Находить похожие вопросы в базе из 2кк записей

Tags: php, mysql, sql, поиск, сравнение

Есть сервис вопрос по разным предметам.

Модераторам необходимо выводить до 5 похожих вопросов к тому, который задал пользователь. Вопросы разные, по физике, математике, химии, информатике и т.д.

В базе больше 2 миллионов вопросов, и постоянно увеличивается, поэтому запрос тяжелым не получится сделать.

Лучшее что я смог попытаться сделать сам, это использовать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: используйте sphinx или elasticsearch

Comment: @nicolas-chabanovsky, перелогиньтесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под "похожестью". Два вопроса, которые совпадают на 90%, но все эти 90% являются стоп-словами, будут похожи?

Я считаю, что для релевантного поиска/сравнения нужна метаинформация, которую и следует сравнивать.

Либо отфильтровывать все, не имеющее отношения к существу вопроса. Но это будет дороже, как мне предствляется.